# How to handle categorical data of a given dataset

Tags: python, data-science, categorical-data

The picture has two columns having nearly 70 000 rows. How to remove categorical data like 1,200,1.2k etc values from a data set?

[image]

We can use replace method, but there are nearly 70 000 rows it is somewhat difficult to handle. So please suggest an appropriate method. Categorical data in the picture is like 1,234 , 1.2k, etc.

Comment: Side note: Do you think loading and viewing 70K rows is a good idea?

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: Would you be able to provide some example code? Ideally this would be as small as possible while demonstrating your problem. For example, you might have something that works, but takes too long to run.